# Cannot create Sencha Touch 2 jsb3 file, TypeError: 'undefined'?

Tags: javascript, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

Currently trying to set up and deploy a Sencha Touch 2 application. I'm following this guide: http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/guide/building

When I went to run `sencha create jsb` the response was:

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function
phantomjs://webpage.evaluate():6
  phantomjs://webpage.evaluate():1
  C:\Program Files (x86)\SenchaSDKTools-2.0.0-beta3\compat\scripts\phantomjs-jsb.js:230
```

What's wrong? Is this a bug with the SDK tool?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some tweaking of the app.json file fixed this problem. Not exactly sure what I did, but I went to build it again and it was fine.